# how to show common Y-Axis using high chart.

Tags: highcharts

I am new for high chart so my requirment is:

1. The dashboard would have two charts side by side and they would use a common Y axis but the x- axis is different.

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks,
Sameek

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? I mean, you simply need to create two charts, side by side, with the same number of points.

Comment: You can try [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack) from highcharts

Comment: @PawełFus:I don't want to generate two chart.Is there any option to configured.

Comment: You can use `left` and `width` options for axes, see: http://jsfiddle.net/w2dgndh7/ - note that `left` and `width` need to be set in pixels, so that solution will work only for fixed-width charts.